# Qual a diferença entre essas duas implementações?

Tags: javascript

Estava lendo alguns artigos sobre *patterns* e me bateu uma dúvida nos dois exemplos a seguir. Suponha que eu tenha uma única função que me retorna um elemento por meio do ID enviado como argumento. O primeiro:

```
var utils = (function(){
    var self = {};

    self.by = function(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    return {
        by: self.by
    };
})();
```

Onde eu poderia chamar a função `by` da seguinte forma:

```
utils.by("campoTexto").innerHTML = "Algum Texto";
```

Agora, um segundo exemplo:

```
var utils2 = (function(){
    return {
      by: function(id){
          return document.getElementById(id);
      }
    };
})();
```

Onde eu poderia chamar a função `by` da seguinte forma:

```
utils2.by("campoTexto").innerHTML = "Algum Texto";
```

A minha dúvida é: Qual a diferença entre essas duas implementações? No primeiro, a função é implementada fora do `return` enquanto na segunda é implementado dentro do `return`, o que isso muda no código?

```js
var utils = (function(){
    var self = {};
    
    self.by = function(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };
    
    return {
        by: self.by
    };
})();


var utils2 = (function(){
    return {
      by: function(id){
          return document.getElementById(id);
      }
    };
})();

utils.by("a").innerHTML = "Usando 'utils'...";
utils2.by("b").innerHTML = "Usando 'utils2'...";
```

```html
<p id='a'></p>
<p id='b'></p>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não muda nada no exemplo que você deu... mas pode ser útil em outras situações.

### Quando faz diferença?

Isso pode ser necessário caso você queira fazer referência ao objeto `self` de dentro da função `by`, sem depender do `this`... ou então associar o `this` de forma mais permanente usando [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (e.g. `by.bind(self)`).

O motivo para tal vantagem é que `this` pode mudar. Mas se a intenção for usar algo que não mude, então será necessário:

- usar `self` dentro de `by`:

  ```
  by: function() { self.qualquerCoisa... ; }
  ```

  Neste caso, mesmo usando [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) ou [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) para chamar o método `by`, ainda assim `self` não seria mudado, ao passo que se usasse `this` o resultado mudaria.
- ou então `by.bind(self)`:

  ```
  by: (function() { this.qualquerCoisa... ; }).bind(self)
  ```

  Neste caso, `this` sempre será igual a `self`, nem mesmo usando `call`/`apply` é possível mudar o comportamento.

**Nota:** que o `this` também muda, quando você copia uma referência a uma função de um lugar para o outro, a não só ao usar `call`/`apply`:

```
var utils2 = ...;
myUtils.by = utils2.by;
// o `this` passado para o `by` abaixo, será `myUtils` e não `utils2`
myUtils.by("campoTexto").innerHTML = "Algum Texto";
```

### Porque não muda nada no exemplo da questão?

Como eu disse, no seu exemplo, não tem diferença de um para o outro. Isso se deve ao fato de que nada levará uma referência de `self` para fora dessa função.

- `self` não é enclosed em na função `by` (não é utilizada numa closure)
- `self` não é copiado para o objeto retornado

Isso quer dizer que nada restará de `self`, pois nenhuma referência restará para ele.

### Snippets para testar as possibilidades

```js
// self original será enclausurado e retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = function(id) {
        return this === self;
    };
    return self;
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // true
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // false
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // false


// self original será enclausurado, mas não retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = function(id) {
        return this === self;
    };
    return {
        by: self.by
    };
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // false
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // false
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // false


// self original será enclausurado, alterado e depois retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = function(id) {
        return this === self;
    };
    self = {
        by: self.by
    };
    return self;
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // true
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // false
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // false


// self original será enclausurado em função com bind e retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = (function(id) {
        return this === self;
    }).bind(self);
    return self;
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // true
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // true
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // true


// self original será enclausurado em função com bind, mas não retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = (function(id) {
        return this === self;
    }).bind(self);
    return {
        by: self.by
    };
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // true
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // true
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // true


// self original será enclausurado em função com bind, alterado e depois retornado
var modulo = (function() {
    var self = {};
    self.by = (function(id) {
        return this === self;
    }).bind(self);
    self = {
        by: self.by
    };
    return self;
})();
escrever(modulo.by()); // false
var outro = { by: modulo.by };
escrever(outro.by()); // false
escrever(modulo.by.call(outro)); // false


function escrever(valor) {
    document.write(valor+"<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Que nó na minha pobre cabecinha...

Comment: @JorgeB. me diz qual é a sua dificuldade para eu poder melhorar a resposta.

Comment: O que quiseste dizer que se eu quisesse usar `self.exemplo` dentro de `by` era possível na primeira implementação é essa a vantagem?

Comment: Exatamente. O motivo para tal vantagem é que `this` pode mudar. Mas se a intenção for usar algo que não mude, então será necessário usar `self` dentro de `by`, ou então `by.bind(self)`.

Comment: Copiei meu comentário anterior para a resposta em si, e dei uma organizada... agora acho que ficou melhor.

Comment: Acho que sim :)

Comment: Quando se usa (por exemplo) `self` dentro do corpo de `by`, isso se chama closure. O significado em portugês é *"clausura"*, e se deve ao fato de a função aprisionar a variável dentro dela, mesmo que saia do contexto em que foi declarada, a variável permanece dentro da função.

Comment: No primeiro caso `self` pode ser diferente de `this`. Se `by` fosse definido assim: `function(){return self===this;}` o resultado poderia ser falso, dependendo da forma que a função vá ser utilizada (e.g. `utils2.by()` // this == utils, logo this != self). Por outro lado, se usar `bind`, ai sim, nunca será diferente. Se `by` for definido como `(function(){return self===this;}).bind(self)` o resultado sempre seria positivo (caso a variável enclausurada não fosse redefinida, tipo `self={novaDefinicao:"self redefinido"}`).

Comment: Adicionei alguns snippets de código, para demonstrar de quais formas o `this` pode ser alterado e de quais formas é possível manter o `self` original.

Comment: Miguel, quis dizer, por exemplo: Supondo que eu vá criar a função `by` (limitando somente à criação) dentro de `utils`. Criá-la usando `self.by(...)` seria a mesma coisa que `this.by(...)`? Ambos são uma função que pertence a `utils`?

Comment: Você tá falando da diferença entre esses códigos: *`self.by=function(){}`* e *`this.by=function(){}`* ?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo exatamente

Comment: A opção usando `this` só funcionaria caso a função fosse chamada com o operador `new`:

**`var modulo = new (function() { this.by = function(id){ }; })();`**